# having problems with android

Tags: android, programmable-completion

Please have a look at the code below:
When I use handler like this I get a warning(This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur )
Can someone tell me what is the best way to do this?

```
private void cacheImages() {

            try {

                    // The handler is inside the function because
                    // normally this function is called once.
                    final Handler cacheHandler = new Handler() {

                    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

                        switch (message.what) {

                        case ThreadState.STARTED:
                            cachingDialog.setMax(message.arg1);
                            break;

                        case ThreadState.PROGRESSION_UPDATE:
                            cachingDialog.setProgress(message.arg1);
                            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you've answered your own question.

You've put a `final` on a cached handler with a `new` keyword inside a function.

This is the compiler warning you NOT do do that. `cacheImages()` can be called more than once, so don't do this!

Can you just declare the handler OUTSIDE of the `cacheImages()` function in the main activity scope?

EDIT: Example

```
            final Handler cacheHandler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message message) {

                    switch (message.what) {

                    case ThreadState.STARTED:
                        cachingDialog.setMax(message.arg1);
                        break;

                    case ThreadState.PROGRESSION_UPDATE:
                        cachingDialog.setProgress(message.arg1);
                        break;
                    }
                }

private void cacheImages() {

        try {
           ... do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           ... do stuff
        }
```